# ng-class applies first class perfectly but the second one does not read the css rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple menu with links `<a>` inside `<li>`. I'm simply using 2 conditions for the `ng-class` : When they are inactive use the 'link-ordenar' class, though when they are active use the 'link-ordenar-active' class.

It works perfectly when it executes the condition for inactive link, and the CSS shows as it should. Though when it changes the css to the 'link-ordenar-active' class, then it does change the class, but it totally disregards my css style sheet where the rules of this class are written....

Heres my HTML angular code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href ng-class="{'link-ordernar':!tabActive('pordescargar'), 'link-ordenar-active':tabActive('pordescargar')}" ng-click="activarTab('pordescargar')">por descargar</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href ng-class="{'link-ordernar':!tabActive('descargado'), 'link-ordenar-active':tabActive('descargado')}" ng-click="activarTab('descargado')">descargado</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href ng-class="{'link-ordernar':!tabActive('regalado'), 'link-ordenar-active':tabActive('regalado')}" ng-click="activarTab('regalado')">regalado</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

I've tried changing the name to not use dashes and only one camelcase word, also adding the style in the same html file...both with same results.

So heres choosing "por descargar" using link-ordenar-active, there is only a default link style
[image]

Heres choosing another item
[image]

The other menu item links are using the link-ordenar class in the first condition of `ng-class` and it evaluates to the css rules of my stylesheet...

The CSS for link-ordenar-active and link-ordenar:

```
.link-ordernar {
   color: #202020;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0px -4px 10px 0px;
   font-size: 25px;
   padding: 0px 10px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link-ordernar-active {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px -4px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    font-family: Fairview_Regular !important;
    color: #202020 !important;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

If I explicitly write `class="link-ordenar-active"` into one of the menu items, it does show the CSS style as it should:
[image]

**UPDATE #1:**

Heres the implementation for tabActive and activarTab:

```
        $scope.activarTab = function(tab){
            $scope.tabActual = tab;
            $scope.cargarMusica();
        };

        $scope.tabActive = function(tab){
            if($scope.tabActual === tab)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean disregard your stylesheet. If the class shows correctly then maybe there is a problem with the CSS instead.

Comment: Well, the HTML element has the class, but if you inspect element it is not getting the rules from the style sheet. Only specifically to the second class.

Comment: If change them around, then it WILL show. So it basically only gets the rules of the first class, whichever it is.

Comment: If it's changing the classes correctly based on the active class, it sounds like the problem may be with you stylesheet instead. Can you also point the relevant parts of the stylesheet?

Comment: If you remove `ng-class` and add `class="link-ordernar-active"` (static class not applied by Angular) does it display correctly?

Comment: If the classes are applied but no css works may be you did not correctly include you're stylesheet.

Comment: @KirillSlatin I just tried that and yes, it displays the CSS correctly... =/

Comment: @NicoSBH well, all my HTML is being rendered from that same stylesheet

Comment: Now it's time to show `tacActive` implementation :). How do you know the class is applied? Do you see it in devtools? What if there is an exception in this func for this case and no class is applied ?

Comment: Update answer with implementation. I know the class is applied because i see it in inspect element, i also dont see any errors or exceptions in the google chrome dev tools, altho i also suspect this might be it...but i just dont see any happening!

Comment: Things are getting tougher. Can you reproduce it in fiddle/plunker or may be you can share a link to your site?

Comment: Wah :( its a rather big site, i only have this git branch on my localhost

Comment: I'll update if I can, thanks anyway!

Comment: Attempt to reproduce it in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can lead to resolution of the problem. If not resolved it becomes a perfect self-evident playground for SO experts that may help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i did a **workaround** for those who might encounter this problem. I haven't figured out why it wont load the second class applied, but since I've got short time on my hands this fix will do for something non-trivial in the project.

So what I did is create 2 elements for each element in the menu, one with the `link-ordenar` class and the other with the `link-ordenar-active` class, and I simply use an `ng-show` to hide them as needed. Heres the code:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href ng-show="!tabActive('pordescargar')" class="link-ordernar" ng-click="activarTab('pordescargar')">por descargar</a>
            <a href ng-show="tabActive('pordescargar')" class="link-ordernar-active" ng-click="activarTab('pordescargar')">por descargar</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href ng-show="!tabActive('descargado')" class="link-ordernar" ng-click="activarTab('descargado')">descargado</a>
            <a href ng-show="tabActive('descargado')" class="link-ordernar-active" ng-click="activarTab('descargado')">descargado</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href ng-show="!tabActive('regalado')" class="link-ordernar"  ng-click="activarTab('regalado')">regalado</a>
            <a href ng-show="tabActive('regalado')" class="link-ordernar-active"  ng-click="activarTab('regalado')">regalado</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```